# Change array into sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have an array in this form

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Textbox
            [label] => Société
            [name] => societe
            [properties] => a:2:{s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";}
            [language] => FR
            [weight] => 1
            [nid] => 2
            [options] => NULL
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => Select
            [label] => 
            [name] => interesstedby
            [properties] => a:3:{s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";s:5:"value";s:2:"-1";}
            [options] => a:1:{s:7:"options";s:31:"-1|Je suis intéressé(e) par";}
            [language] => FR
            [weight] => 6
            [nid] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [type] => Select
            [label] => 
            [name] => referrer
            [properties] => a:3:{s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";s:5:"value";s:2:"-1";}
            [options] => a:1:{s:7:"options";s:4:"Test";}
            [language] => FR
            [weight] => 7
            [nid] => 2
            [options] => NULL
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [type] => Textarea
            [label] => Message
            [name] => message
            [properties] => a:3:{s:8:"required";b:1;s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";}
            [language] => FR
            [weight] => 8
            [nid] => 2
            [options] => NULL
        )

)
```

And in order to change to an `INSERT INTO` kind of a query I use rhis function:

```
function insert_contact($array){
    $values = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value){       
        $columns = array_keys($value);
        $values[] = "('" . implode("', '", array_values($value))."')";
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `".'form' . "` (`".implode("`, `", $columns)."`)";
    $sql .= " VALUES ".implode(',', $values) .";";
    return $sql;
}
```

As you notice that I take `key_values` and put them into the column of the table.The issue here is the order of the keys since it generate a wrong sql file (for example the 1st element of the array has `[options]` at the last and the others has the same element ) I tried `ksort()` but still!

What's the error in my code? Thanks 
The current sql query :

```
INSERT INTO `form` (`type`, `label`, `name`, `properties`, `language`, `weight`, `nid`,`options`) VALUES 
('Textbox', 'Société', 'societe', 'a:2:{s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";}', 'FR', '1', '2',NULL),
('Select', '', 'interesstedby', 'a:3:{s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";s:5:"value";s:2:"-1";}', 'a:1:{s:7:"options";s:31:"-1|Je suis intéressé(e) par";}', 'FR', '2', '2',NULL),
('Select', '', 'referrer', 'a:3:{s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";s:5:"value";s:2:"-1";}', 'a:1:{s:7:"options";s:4:"Test";}', 'FR', '3', '2',NULL),
('Textarea', 'Message', 'message', 'a:3:{s:8:"required";b:1;s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";}', 'FR', '4', '2',NULL);
```

The expected :

```
INSERT INTO `form` (`type`, `label`, `name`, `properties`, `language`, `weight`, `nid`,`options`) VALUES 
('Textbox', 'Société', 'societe', 'a:2:{s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";}', 'FR', '1', '2',NULL),
('Select', '', 'interesstedby', 'a:3:{s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";s:5:"value";s:2:"-1";}', 'a:1:{s:7:"options";s:31:"-1|Je suis intéressé(e) par";}', 'FR', '2', '2'),
('Select', '', 'referrer', 'a:3:{s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";s:5:"value";s:2:"-1";}', 'a:1:{s:7:"options";s:4:"Test";}', 'FR', '3', '2'),
('Textarea', 'Message', 'message', 'a:3:{s:8:"required";b:1;s:11:"class_label";s:8:"col-md-4";s:5:"class";s:8:"col-md-8";}', 'FR', '4', '2',NULL),
```

Comment: Please add the expected output (SQL string) to the question

Comment: I see the problem. Not all arrays have the same columns or the same order. You will first have to go through all rows and find the columns and decide an order. Then you go through all rows again and generate the value part in that order that you decided before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the array to be sorted the same way. You mentioned ksort so I don't know why you didn't manage to fix it. All the arrays have the same columns even if they are empty and the master array uses implied indexes, so you really only need to add one line `ksort($value);`.

```
function insert_contact($array){
    $values = array();
    foreach($array as $i => $row){
        ksort($row); // <-------------------- here
        if (!$i) $columns = array_keys($row); // only need to do this once
        $values[] = "('" . implode("', '", $row)."')";
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `".'form' . "` (`".implode("`, `", $columns)."`)";
    $sql .= " VALUES ".implode(',', $values) .";";
    return $sql;
}

$array = array(
  array('description' => 'blah1', 'id' => 1,),
  array('id' => 2, 'description' => 'blah2',),
  array('description' => 'blah3','id' => 3, ),
  array('id' => 4, 'description' => 'blah4',),
  array('id' => 5, 'description' => 'blah5',),
);

echo insert_contact($array);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d27eba052b7dc2a1d80d2200d18fd6b72cc2e3df

Also there was no need to use `array_values()` and you should sanitize those fields to prevent sql injection if you haven't already.

Just another note, you would normally reuse a function like this, so create `function insert_bulk($table, $array)`. Full code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b329cd9ff2c4ee0946695a7dd15532c09e70f9f8

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that handles that not all keys exists in all rows. It first goes through and find all keys. And then generate the values in the same order. Add NULL if the row doesn't have a value for that key.

```
$var = array(
  array(
    'type' => 'Type 1',
    'options' => 'Options 1',
  ),
  array(
    'type' => 'Type 2',
    'name' => 'Name 2',
  ),
);

$keys = array();
foreach ($var as $fields) {
  $keys = array_merge($keys, $fields);
}

$keys = array_keys($keys);

$values = array();
foreach ($var as $fields) {
  $field_values = array();
  foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $field_values[] = array_key_exists($key, $fields) ? '\''. $fields[$key] .'\'' : 'NULL';
  }
  $values[] = '('. implode(',', $field_values) .')';
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO `table` (`'. implode('`,`', $keys) .'`) VALUES '. implode(',', $values);

var_dump($sql);
```

And a demo here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fcd4e6af0891b30a181b22e80f9a8cb8e10551f0

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

```
function insert_contact ($array) {
    foreach ($array) {
        $keys = array();
        $values = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            $keys[] = $key;
            $values[] = $value;
        }
        $query = 'INSERT INTO `form`
                  (`'.implode('`, `', $keys).'`)
                  VALUES("'.implode('", "', $values).'")';
        return $query;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21f481f91315e67dcf74abc08fc162e1422cb915)

Comment: That shouldn't work because the column list will be repeated `count($array)` times instead of once followed by `VALUE (...), (...), (...)`

Comment: I think all the keys and values will be stored in the `$keys` and `$values` variables?

Comment: No you've misunderstood the question or don't understand the syntax.

Comment: Can you see the post again?

Comment: @Popnoodles I added a demo and I think it is working?

Comment: look at the array OP gave. It has multiple rows and the columns are not in the same order. Your array is nothing like that, it's a single row.